# Prove that $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1} =1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm stuck proving that $$\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1} =1/2$$

I managed to prove that the sequence was increasing, bounced by $1$ and computation shows the limit is likely to be $1/2$...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure the limit isn't 1/2? Roughly speaking, we expect the only term to matter is when $k=1$.

Comment: @mixedmath for p=4 you get 0.947.... And 0.985 for p=5

Comment: And for $p=100$?

Comment: Even worse  http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP17751i2777eg3dg09cg20000602d9eeie7cb4bih?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=39&w=443.&h=20.

Comment: I mistyped the expression,  this is 1/2 indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{p}+1}=\frac{1}{2}+S(p)$$
And the simple inequality:
$$|S(p)|\leq\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}+1}\leq\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}}=\zeta(p)-1$$
Which gives us:
$$\implies \lim_{p\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: There's a little typo in the second equality. Nice solution anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To interchange limit and sum we prove that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}$$ is uniformly convergent. Indeed since this is an alternating series the desired result follows easily using this inequality

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}\right|\le \frac {1}{(n+1)^p+1}\le \frac 1 n \quad\forall p\ge1$$
hence
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}=\frac12+\lim_{p\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}=\frac12+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Idea about the comment by mixedmath:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(p)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^p+1},$$
and if you prove the uniform convergence of this series of functions...